# Embedding a Google Visualization Chart inside a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-chart-api

Unfortunately, the [embedded charts in Google Spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#Spreadsheet_Charts) do not have the customization I want. I would like to use a [Google Visualization Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart) instead. The documentation [discusses how to use a Google Spreadsheet as a datasource](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#Google_Spreadsheets_as_a_Data_Source), but the problem is that this requires you to give permission to view the spreadsheet itself to the chart to run the query.

This could be worked around if I could embed the chart within the Google Visualization so that I don't need to allow outside access, but I can't see any way to do that.

I am open for potential solutions to this problem that will:

1. Allow me to not share my spreadsheet publicly
2. Allow me to use Google Visualization to create a chart of the data in the spreadsheet
3. Preferably do it within the Google Docs environment (rather than having to create a separate HTML file or store it on a separate site like jsfiddle)

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/78200/88163. There you will find a hint / partial answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there isn't a way to do that. Instead, create a Web App as it accomplish the three requirements.

**Reference**
[Web apps and Google Sites Gadgets - Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)