# How to access a gauge chart in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-charts

I have a gauge chart in my spreadsheet. I am looking for a line for accessing it.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Gauge");
  var charts = sheet.getCharts();
  var crt = charts[0];

  return(charts.length);
}
```

The problem is that `sheet.getCharts()` does not seem to encompass gauge charts. I have tested that by inserting a line chart into the same sheet. `return(charts.length);` then returned `1`.

[image: gauge chart and line chart]

How to access the gauge chart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue with Google Spreadsheets, first reported [a year ago](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4197). You can star the issue in the hope of increasing its importance. So far, the response from Google is

> Thank you for your report. We have been able to reproduce the problem and have filed it internally.

Since `getCharts` is [the only Sheet method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) returning embedded charts, Apps Scripts cannot access the charts that `getCharts` does not support. Gauge is not the only type that lacks such support: same issue exists with some other types listed under "Other", e.g., Polar and Sparkline types.

---

My impression is that Google shifted resources toward Google Charts API, which is not tied to Spreadsheets. It does support [Gauge charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge) as well as many other types. If you require programmatic access to gauge charts and are okay with them not being in a spreadsheet, this may be your best bet. A standalone script can still get data from a published spreadsheet, but of course this process will involve a bit more coding than with a spreadsheet-bound script.

Related: [Embedding a Google Visualization Chart inside a Google Spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/65810/embedding-a-google-visualization-chart-inside-a-google-spreadsheet?rq=1)

Comment: A brilliant answer! Thanks for all the references, I did star the issue, although I don't feel they would fix it soon, especially when [Google Code is going off](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html). Very thanks for your insights on how I could go around my problem, I'll try to explore them in more detail.